# TPM 2.0 - could not load "libtss2-tcti-tabrmd.so.0"

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-20-04) and am not getting very far.
I am using a pretty basic digital ocean VPS running latest ubuntu 20.04, and am getting this error when trying to create the certificate authority.

> kieran@azuracast:~$ pki --gen --type rsa --size 4096 --outform pem >
> ~/pki/private/ca-key.pem
> TPM 2.0 - could not load "libtss2-tcti-tabrmd.so.0"
> plugin 'tpm': failed to load - tpm_plugin_create returned NULL
> kieran@azuracast:~$

It seems someone else in the comments was getting this but there are no replies.
Any thoughts?

Comment: "libtss2-tcti-tabrmd.so.0" : `sudo apt install libtss2-tcti-tabrmd0` from the **universe** repo https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libtss2-tcti-tabrmd0 ......... Ref. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libtss2-tcti-tabrmd.so.0

Answer (score 52):

Installing the following package resolved the issue for me:

```
libtss2-tcti-tabrmd0
```